# Ignoring commas in attribute value while writing to csv file

Tags: awk

i am a newbie to awk and trying to accomplish converting an ldif file to csv, for that here i am using awk to parse and convert it. below script is working fine if the attribute value dont have any comma in it..But if the attribute value has a comma in it, in csv it making a separate column.
so Needed help in manipulating the attribute value field if it contains a comma using awk..
Below is the awk file i am using and the sample data.
AWK script:-

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
        uid = ""
        omEntitytype = ""
        sn = ""
        givenName = ""
        initials = ""
        omUnit = ""
        departmentNumber = ""
        omCostCenter = ""
        title = ""
        omManager = ""
        omaffiliatedaccount = ""
        printf("USERID,USER_TYPE,USER_LASTNAME,USER_FIRSTNAME,USER_INITIAL,USER_UNIT,USER_DEPT,CHARGE_UNIT,USER_JOB_TITLE,SPONSOR_USERID,ACCOUNT_ID\n");
}
/^uid:/              {uid=$2}
/^omEntitytype:/       {omEntitytype=$2}
/^sn:/              {sn=$2}
/^givenName:/          {givenName=$2}
/^initials:/               {initials=$2}
/^omUnit:/              {omUnit=$2}
/^departmentNumber:/      {departmentNumber=$2}
/^omCostCenter:/      {omCostCenter=$2}
/^title:/ {title=$2}
/^omManager:/            {omManager=$2}
/^omaffiliatedaccount:/          {omaffiliatedaccount=$2}
/^dn/{
        if(uid != "") printf("%s,%s,%s,,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",uid,omEntitytype,sn,givenName,initials,omUnit,departmentNumber,omCostCenter,title,omManager,omaffiliatedaccount);
        uid = ""
        omEntitytype = ""
        sn = ""
        givenName = ""
        initials = ""
        omUnit = ""
        departmentNumber = ""
        omCostCenter = ""
        title = ""
        omManager = ""
        omaffiliatedaccount = ""
}
#capture last dn
END{
       if(uid != "") printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",uid,omEntitytype,sn,givenName,initials,omUnit,departmentNumber,omCostCenter,title,omManager,omaffiliatedaccount)
}
```

---

sample ldif data to pass to it

```
dn: uid=sample1,o=people,dc=om,DC=COM
uid: sample1
omEntitytype: Contingent, off-Site
sn: sample1 name1
givenName: sample1
initials: P
omUnit: 07
departmentNumber: 123
omCostCenter: 10
title: Analyst
omaffiliatedaccount: 12345

dn: uid=sample2,o=people,dc=om,DC=COM
uid: sample2
omEntitytype: Contingent, On-Site
sn: sample2 name2
givenName: sample2
initials: P
omUnit: 07
departmentNumber: 123
omCostCenter: 10
title: PLAT MGR, ENGINE,HYD,ELECT,DRIVES
omaffiliatedaccount: 12345
```

here in the sample data, i am having problem(filling to new column in csv) for fields omEntitytype and title, as they have ',' in value..

any help is appreciated..thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't shown us the expected output or told us how you want to handle the commas in your data - escape them? quote them? replace them? Something else? Edit your question to show the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have name -> value pairs in your data it's a good idea to build a similar mapping array first and then print the values by name:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = ","
    numFlds = split("uid omEntitytype sn givenName initials omUnit departmentNumber omCostCenter title omManager omaffiliatedaccount",flds)
    print "USERID,USER_TYPE,USER_LASTNAME,USER_FIRSTNAME,USER_INITIAL,USER_UNIT,USER_DEPT,CHARGE_UNIT,USER_JOB_TITLE,SPONSOR_USERID,ACCOUNT_ID"
}
{
    name = value = $0
    sub(/:.*/,"",name)
    sub(/[^:]*:[[:space:]]*/,"",value)
    name2value[name] = value
}
!NF { prtRec() }
END { prtRec() }

function prtRec() {
    for (i=1; i<=numFlds; i++) {
        printf "\"%s\"%s", name2value[flds[i]], (i<numFlds?OFS:ORS)
    }
    delete name2value
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
USERID,USER_TYPE,USER_LASTNAME,USER_FIRSTNAME,USER_INITIAL,USER_UNIT,USER_DEPT,CHARGE_UNIT,USER_JOB_TITLE,SPONSOR_USERID,ACCOUNT_ID
"sample1","Contingent, off-Site","sample1 name1","sample1","P","07","123","10","Analyst","","12345"
"sample2","Contingent, On-Site","sample2 name2","sample2","P","07","123","10","PLAT MGR, ENGINE,HYD,ELECT,DRIVES","","12345"
```

You didn't actually tell us how you want the commas handled, the above quotes them but if that's not what you want then just change `prtRec()` to do whatever it is you do want, e.g. maybe `gsub(/,/,";",name2value[flds[i]])`.

Note that if your input data wasn't missing some fields that you want output and/or if you just wanted fields output in the order they appear in the input then the above would be quite a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks Morton..your solution did worked out..If you have time, can you pls explain your logic..as i was new to awk not able to get the  suv part..thanks again for your help Morton.

Comment: Awesome solution. Exactly what I was searching for. Thank you @Ed Morton

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my ignorance but could you not just use a different character (such as a '/') to separate multiple titles?

Comment: hi, for the ldif data I am using ':'  as a delimiter which distinguish between attribute name and value..so i am trying to convert it into a csv file.so while converting using awk, the attribute value of omEntitytype and title are getting in new columns in csv, as in the value there is an ',' ..so need help in ignoring the comma while writing to csv..

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether "," exist in the field and either you can change it to another char or quote the field (which is standard)

Here is prototype for you for the latter case

```
echo "a:b,c:d" | 
awk -F: -v q='"' -v OFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                                 if(match($i,",")) $i=q $i q}1'

a,"b,c",d
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this (requires GNU awk)

```
generate LDIF | gawk '
    function quote(str) {
        if (str ~ /,/) str = "\"" str "\""
        return str
    }
    function print_record() { 
        if (data["uid"] != "") 
            printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n",
                quote(data["uid"]),
                quote(data["omEntitytype"]),
                quote(data["sn"]),
                quote(data["givenName"]),
                quote(data["initials"]),
                quote(data["omUnit"]),
                quote(data["departmentNumber"]),
                quote(data["omCostCenter"]),
                quote(data["title"]),
                quote(data["omManager"]),
                quote(data["omaffiliatedaccount"])
    }
    match($0, /^([^:]+): (.*)/, m) {data[m[1]] = m[2]}
    NF == 0 {print_record(); delete data}
    END {print_record()}
'
```

This outputs, given your sample input

```
sample1,"Contingent, off-Site",sample1 name1,sample1,P,07,123,10,Analyst,,12345
sample2,"Contingent, On-Site",sample2 name2,sample2,P,07,123,10,"PLAT MGR, ENGINE,HYD,ELECT,DRIVES",,12345
```

Comment: Yes. I'll update that. I did use a regex at first that, in hindsight, was more robust

Comment: Nice use of gawk match() for that!